# Unclear instructions to install Laravel Telescope in dev only

Tags: laravel

I was trying to install [Laravel Telescope](https://github.com/laravel/telescope) in my local dev environment. According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/telescope), to install it in specific environments

> you should remove the `TelescopeServiceProvider` service provider registration from your `app` configuration file. Instead, manually register the service provider in the `register` method of your `AppServiceProvider`:

But I didn't find Telescope being registered in my `app` configuration file. I have no clue where the registration takes place. I'm using a fresh Laravel install, and the `/telescope` route works.

Why is it not registered in `config/app.php` as mentioned in the docs?

Comment: Did you run `php artisan telescope:install` ? I just did it and I DO have `App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider::class` in my `config/app.php`

Comment: Yes, I did. I've done it thrice since. What command did you use to install Telescope from Composer?

Comment: I did `composer require laravel/telescope` the parameter `--dev` shouldn't change in your case. Do you have this **exact** string (with the comma): `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,` in your `config/app.php`? `telescope:install` command looks for it.

Comment: Yes, I do. Does that help narrow it down?

Comment: Yes, the command looks for this line to add TelescopeServiceProvider. https://github.com/laravel/telescope/blob/1.0/src/Console/InstallCommand.php#L63

Comment: But if Telescope isn't registered, why is it still working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185142/discussion-between-cbaconnier-and-mav).